# looping through constructors in Java Script

Tags: javascript, loops, constructor

I'm putting together an online quiz and would like to construct many questions. I've made a class constructor (see below). And I've set up variables for input, which are different for each question. I'd like to iterate through their construction but I don't see how to loop through and increase the object names (e.g., q1, q2, etc.) and arguments that I pass (e.g., answer0, answer1, etc.) using the constructor. Any help would be very appreciated! I think it makes sense if you look at the code below. I know there must be a more efficient way.

```
let quest = []; //array of question objects

//question constructor
class Question {
  constructor(question, answer, hint, icon, congrats, image, location) {
    this.answer = answer;
    this.congrats = congrats;
    this.hint = hint;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.image = image;
    this.location = location;
    this.question = question;
    this.pushToQuest = function () {
      quest.push(this);
    };

    this.pushToQuest();
  }
}

// Question 0 input (actual text removed)
let question0 = "?";
let answer0 = ["", "", "", "", ""];
let hint0 = ["", "", "", "", ""];
let icon0 = "fa-utensils-alt";
let image0 = "img/001.jpg";
let congrats0 = "That's right.... ";
let location0 = '';

const q0 = new Question(
  question0,
  answer0,
  hint0,
  icon0,
  congrats0,
  image0,
  location0
);
```

Comment: There's nothing to loop through. You only have one questino, one answer ... one location

Comment: `let questions = [{ "q" : "What is ....", "a" : "It is a ....", "hint":"It is grey", "icon":"", "congrats": "You guessed the elephant","image":"elephant.jpg","location":"Africa" }, { "q" : "What is ....", "a" : "It is a ....", ... }, .... ]` Then you can use `questions.forEach(q => Object.entries(q).forEach....)`

Comment: @mplungjan I've realized that if he did that, there would be no real point to the `Question` class at all, since all the Question class does is push objects that look not too dissimilar to that onto the `quest` array

Comment: Thanks, to clarify, I posted 1 example, but there are dozens more questions in the same format.

Comment: @TKoL Yes exactly. No point in a question class

Comment: @ChrisRichardson Please reload to see my updated comment

Comment: @ChrisRichardson are the questions coming from a database or something? How do you get them in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution will be to create a json file containing a list of question objects like this

```
[
    {
         "question": "some question",
         "answer": ["", "", "", "", ""];
         "hint": ["", "", "", "", ""];
         "icon": "fa-utensils-alt";
         "image": "img/001.jpg";
         "congrats": "That's right.... ";
         "location": "";
    },
    {
         "question": "some question",
         "answer": ["", "", "", "", ""];
         "hint": ["", "", "", "", ""];
         "icon": "fa-utensils-alt";
         "image": "img/001.jpg";
         "congrats": "That's right.... ";
         "location": "";
    }

]
```

And then fetch the data, and use a for each loop on it to create a constructor and append each constructor to the quest list

```
async function (fetchedJson) {
    fetchedJson.forEach((item) => {
        const que = new Question(
            item.question,
            item.answer,
            item.hint,
            item.icon,
            item.image,
            item.congrats,
            item.location
        )

        quest.push(que)
    })
}
```

Forgive my code if there are syntax errors because I'm typing with my tablet

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful

Comment: Basically my comment in an answer